# Ubuntu Cmake: Parse error in command line argument

Tags: opencv, opengl, ubuntu, terminal, cmake

I've been trying to install Opencv in a virtual machine with Ubuntu, but when I try to make the file with the following command:

```
cmake -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D 
INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON 
-D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON ..
```

No matter what I update or re-install, I keep getting:

```
Parse error in command line argument -D 
Should be: VAR:type=value
Cmake Error: No cmake script provided
Cmake Error: Problem processing arguments. Aborting.
```

I've already tried lots of solutions, including:
[Trying to build OpenCV 2.4.1 with OpenGL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035500/trying-to-build-opencv-2-4-1-with-opengl-support)
wich seemed to be the most logic but either ways in my case it didn't work.

Comment: try to remove the spaces between the -D and the args, like: -DWITH_TBB=ON

Comment: Thank actually worked perfectly, I just removed all the spaces like this: cmake -DWITH_TBB=ON -DBUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -DWITH_V4L=ON -DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON ..

Thank you very much!

Comment: @GhaamaeEos please make your last comment into an answer and accept that.