# converting from opencv to opencl for powerful usage of raspberry pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I am working on raspberry pi in image processing project using opencv

But i found that it was inefficient with raspberry pi as it works on CPU and don't use powerful GPU and i must switch to openCL

Are there any method to convert from openCV to openCL

Or how can i able GPU for opencv ?

Or how i can i use opencv with acceptable fast response processing on raspberry pi ?

Comment: Probably not, because they do different things. You can [build OpenCV with OpenGL support](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11035500/1816580), but that will probably don't do much for you. It just [adds interoperability functions](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/core/doc/opengl_interop.html) from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL modules are included in OpenCV. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ocl/doc/introduction.html

use it.