# Build OpenCV 3.0 with OpenGL and GTK on LMDE2 (Debian 8.2)

Tags: opengl, gtk, opencv3.0

I've built the opencv with `cmake -DWITH_OPENGL=ON ..`, but the output of the cmake tell me the OpenGL supported is **NO**.

And I've checked the cmake cache to assure the `WITH_OPENGL` is `ON`.

The GUI used is GTK+ 3.0, and the *libgtkglext1-dev* is installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After reading the cmake script `cmake/OpenCVFindLibsGUI.cmake`, I've found the related cmake codes:

```
# --- GTK ---
ocv_clear_vars(HAVE_GTK HAVE_GTK3 HAVE_GTHREAD HAVE_GTKGLEXT)
if(WITH_GTK AND NOT HAVE_QT)
  # ...
  if(WITH_OPENGL AND NOT HAVE_GTK3)
    CHECK_MODULE(gtkglext-1.0 HAVE_GTKGLEXT) # MARK1
  endif()
endif()

# --- OpenGl ---
ocv_clear_vars(HAVE_OPENGL HAVE_QT_OPENGL)
if(WITH_OPENGL)
  if(WITH_WIN32UI OR (HAVE_QT AND QT_QTOPENGL_FOUND) OR HAVE_GTKGLEXT) # MARK2
    find_package (OpenGL QUIET)
  # ...
  endif ()
endif(WITH_OPENGL)
```

For I use the GTK+ 3.0, so the statement marked with `MARK1` will not be executed, then the condition marked with `MARK2` will be false. So the OpenGL package will not be loaded.

I've also tried to force to call `CHECK_MODULE(gtkglext-1.0 HAVE_GTKGLEXT)` even when `HAVE_GTK3` is true, but I found compiling compiling error at last.

So I update my building command as below

```
cmake -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DWITH_GTK_2_X=ON ..
```

With `WITH_GTK_2_X` to be set on, the gtk2 is force to be used instead of gtk3.