# OpenGL Support with OpenCV-3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl, opengl-es

I built the `Opencv-3` with `OpenGL` support but I received an error when I execute a basic program:

```
No OpenGL support (Library was built without OpenGL support) in 
cvNamedWindow, file /home/usr/kinect/opencv-
3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp, line 1048
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/usr/kinect/opencv-
3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:1048: error: (-218) Library was 
built without OpenGL support in function cvNamedWindow**
```

When I built the `opencv` I did it with the usual `-D_WITH_OPENGL=0N`
and when was done I could clearly see that was correctly supported with the message `WITH_OPENGL` and so on.

Is there any problem when you try to work with the latest version of `OpenCV` and `OpenGL`?

Do I need to install some special and additional packet or sth?

Thanks, :).

Answer (score 3):

probably need to install OpenGL first. To do so:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkglext1 libgtkglext1-dev
```

find more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035500/trying-to-build-opencv-2-4-1-with-opengl-support/11067289).