# error: (-218:No OpenGL support) Library was built without OpenGL support in function 'namedWindow_'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

fr=0.00
alpha=1.0

bgimg=cv2.imread("background.jpg")

B=np.zeros([Frame_hight,Frame_width,3])

cv2.namedWindow("normImg",cv2.WINDOW_OPENGL)
cv2.namedWindow("Frame",cv2.WINDOW_OPENGL)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Projects/PycharmProjects/FootballTrackingAI/Hakki_Background_Subtraction_v3.py", line 23, in 
cv2.namedWindow("normImg",cv2.WINDOW_OPENGL)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1080: error: (-218:No OpenGL support) Library was built without OpenGL support in function 'namedWindow_'

Comment: either don't create an opengl window or rebuild opencv with opengl support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to build OpenCV 2.4.1 with OpenGL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035500/trying-to-build-opencv-2-4-1-with-opengl-support)